# How to read a line in BufferedInputStream?

Tags: java, input, user-input, bufferedinputstream

I am writing a code to read Input from user by using BufferedInputStream, But as BufferedInputStream reads the bytes my program only read first byte and prints it.
Is there any way I can read/store/print the whole input ( which will Integer ) besides just only reading first byte ?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class EnormousInputTest{

public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        BufferedInputStream bf = new BufferedInputStream(System.in)   ;
    try{
            char c = (char)bf.read();

        System.out.println(c);
    }
finally{
        bf.close();
}   
}   
}
```

OutPut:

[shadow@localhost codechef]$ java EnormousInputTest 
5452
5

Comment: Why don't you use a `BufferedReader` instead?

Comment: I have to process approx 2.5 MB/S , And as per CodeChef BufferedInputStream is the fastest one.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A [`BufferedInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) is used to read *bytes*. Reading a line involves reading *characters*.

You need a way to convert input bytes to characters which is defined by a *charset*. So you should use a `Reader` which converts bytes to characters and from which you can read characters. [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) also has a [`readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) method which reads a whole line, use that:

```
BufferedInputStream bf = new BufferedInputStream(System.in)

BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(bf, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

String line = r.readLine();
System.out.println(line);
```

Comment: +`Long.MAX_VALUE` for actually explaining why the OP needs a `Reader`. There are so many answers simply reading "use this instead: [pasted code]".

Answer (score 3):

You can run this inside a while loop.

Try below code

```
BufferedInputStream bf = new BufferedInputStream(System.in)   ;
    try{
        int i;
        while((i = bf.read()) != -1) {
            char c = (char) i;
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
    finally{
        bf.close();
    }
}
```

But keep in mind this solution is inefficient than using `BufferedReader`  since `InputStream.read()` make a system call for each character read

Comment: If it's so bad, it doesn't probably belong at a site that's supposed to teach _good_ practices :^)

Comment: There are times when the input stream never finishes a line (has no end of line character).  In this case, reading character by character might be the only way to proceed.

Comment: Fine for my case: Had to compute some commands from socket as strings and the rest as a file. perfect solution!